# INSTALAR FULLCALENDAR JS

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Buen dia
Estoy intentando utilizar "FullCalendar Js", pero al tratar de mostrarlo e inicializarlo no me aparece nada

Me voy a la página principal y al buscar la última actualización en los archivos solo me aparece el archivo "index.global" sin archivo css. Estoy llamando el archivo .min asi:

```
<script src="../../../../lib/assets/js/index.global.min.js"></script>
```

Y lo estoy inicializando asi:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        height: 50
    });
    calendar.render();
});
```

Quisiera saber si me pudieran ayudar, porque nose si estoy descargando el archivo incorrecto o lo estoy inicializando de manera incorrecta. Les agradecería bastante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podría ser que no esté cargando bien la ruta del fichero `index.global.min.js`, asegúrate de que por consola no se te esté arrojando un error `404`. También debes tener un `<div>` al que referenciar desde tu JS para que se renderice el calendario. En tu caso debes tener uno con el ID `calendar`.

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional para que puedas ver como se comporta (extraído de la documentación oficial de la librería).

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.4/index.global.min.js'></script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

**Referencia:** [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals)